# What is a cabal component?

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
cabal v2-repl cardano-node
cabal: Cannot open a repl for multiple components at once. The target
'cardano-node' refers to the package cardano-node-1.18.0 which includes the
libraries cardano-node-config and cardano-node.

The reason for this limitation is that current versions of ghci do not support
loading multiple components as source. Load just one component and when you
make changes to a dependent component then quit and reload.
```

I'm trying to enter a cabal repl, but it's not clear what is meant by `component`, does it mean either a executable or library? If so, then how do I refer to/'target' a executable explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

A component is anything behind a stanza with its own set of dependencies, etc. So it can be multiple sublibraries, multiple executables, test-suites, etc. You can prefix component names with `lib:` or `exe:` to specify if its an executable component (like a test suite) or a library component.

Components are described a bit in the users guide https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-commands.html?highlight=component#runhaskell-setup-hs-configure

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer found in a random github issue:
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4602#issuecomment-357471623

We can specify the executable explicitly with:

```
cabal v2-repl exe:nameOfExecutable
```